# can't git rm a directory

Tags: git, rm

I accidentally added a directory to the list of items i'm supposed to git commit.  Now when I try to run a git rm dirname, I get the error

```
rm 'dirname'
fatal: git rm: 'dirname': Is a directory
```

I tried the following commands `git rm -rf dirname` and `git rm dirname --force`, but none of these worked.  They all produced the same error message.

How do I prevent dirname from being committed?

I am using git version 1.7.0.4

Thanks

**Additional Notes**

Ok, it appears `git rm -rf dirname` works only under some conditions.  I ran some tests and normally it works.  However, it will fail if `dirname` is itself a separately controlled git repository with a .git directory in it.  I have this set up because `dirname` is a git controlled framework shared by many of my projects.

Comment: What version of git are you using? What error message do you get when using `git rm -rf dirname`?

Comment: runnign that command gave me same error as above.  I am running git version 1.7.0.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Barring any permissions issues...

`git rm --cached -r dirname`

This should remove the directory from the staged commits.

At this point, it should be untracked and it may be a good idea to set it up to be ignored via [gitignore](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).

Comment: MUCH cleaner/easier than my solutions.

Comment: _WHY_ does git make an operation this simple so complicated?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting `fatal: pathspec 'lib' did not match any files` unfortunately when running this command.

Answer (score 1):

Never had this problem (so no promises that this will work and/or not destroy your data - working on a backup of your repository would be best!), but some options:

---

Option 1 (if you haven't committed locally):

- `git stash` any valuable changes you've made.
- `git reset` your tree (probably need to do `git reset --hard HEAD`)
- `git unstash` your stashed changes and add/commit them carefully.

  ---

Option 2 (If you haven't committed locally, or if you have but there's a remote you haven't pushed to yet):

- `git clone` a clean version of the repository
- Carefully copy your changes over there
- add/commit your changes carefully.

---

Option 3 (which makes a mess of your repo):

- Commit your mistake to the repository.
- Clean up using `git rm -r`

(You don't want to do this if the contents of that directory are huge, obviously.)